# How to reference handlers in sub-directories in serverless-offline?

Tags: python, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

> Windows 10 64bits
>
> Node v12.16.3
>
> Serverless 1.71.3
>
> serverless-offline 6.1.7

**DIRECTORY**:

```
root:
- package.json
- /sub
-- __init__.py
-- sub_handler.py
- ...
- handler.py
- serverless.yml
```

Hi, I'm currently trying to test locally two lambda functions using serverless-offline.
It's working for the handler in the root directory **but it seems that serverless-offline can't reference other handlers in sub-directories**..

**How can I reference handlers in a sub-directory?**

PS: This configuration works when deployed to AWS LAMBDA. I can post both paths.

**Error when I try to post hello2:**

> [offline] Loading handler...
>   (C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\serverless-offline\sub\sub_handler)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\serverless-offline\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\handler-runner\python-runner\invoke.py",
>   line 75, in
>
> ```
>     module = import_module(args.handler_path.replace('/', '.'))
> File "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 126, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>
> ```
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load   
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub\sub_handler'

**serverless.yml**:

```
service: sls-offline-test    
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}    
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: POST
  hello2:
    handler: sub/sub_handler.hello2
    events:
      - http:
          path: 'hello2'
          method: POST    
package:
  individually: true    
  include:
    - sub/**
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I was getting the same problem, I updated the version of serverless-offline plugin and worked out for me